# Why non polar liquids wet non polar surfaces better than polar surfaces?

Tags: surface-chemistry, adhesion

In semiconductor industry adhesion promoters (such as [HMDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bis(trimethylsilyl)amine)) are applied on various surfaces to improve adhesion between the surface and the photoresist:

> On SiO<sub>2</sub> and many metals surfaces, the air humidity forms polaric
>   OH-bonds. Such substrates are hydrophilic, but reveal a bad wetting
>   and adhesion of the unpolaric resist. Adhesion promoters make
>   hydrophilic surfaces hydrophobic thus improving the resist adhesion.
>   [...] **The  methyl  groups  of  the  HMDS  fragment  hereby  form  a 
>   hydrophobic  surface thus improving resist wetting and adhesion**.
>   ([source](http://www.microchemicals.com/technical_information/substrate_cleaning_adhesion_photoresist.pdf))

But why should non polar (hydrophobic) substances wet non polar substrates better than polar substrates? (in the opposite case of **polar substances** it is clear why)

Comment: You mean if the polar substance can't move to get away from the nonpolar liquid, what should keep the latter from forcing itself on the former? A static dipole should be able to induce a dipole moment in the hydrophobic, and attraction should follow?